# I am writing tests for users, and am getting this error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
$ Rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:
in `load': /Users/Tish/Projects/trainer-project/spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

here is user_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  it "requires a name" do
    John = User.new(name: nil, email: 'me@gmail.com', password: 'password')
    expect(John).not_to_be_valid
    expect(John.errors[:name].any?).to_be_truthy
  end
```

the error message points to these lines saying it expects 'end', but end is there...

```
  it "requires an email" do
    John = User.new(name: 'John', email: nil, password: 'password')
    expect(John).not_to_be_valid
    expect(John.errors[:email].any?)to_be_truthy
  end

  it "requires a password" do
    John = User.new(name: 'John', email: 'me@gmail.com', password: nil)
    expect(John).not_to_be_valid
    expect(John.errors[:password].any?)to_be_truthy
  end
end
```

Comment: The dot before `to_be_truthy`is missing ? Should be `expect(John.errors[:email].any?).to_be_truthy`

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers), you want `to be_truthy` (along with the missing dot as @RareFever points out).